# using drawable in simpleadapter

Tags: android, adapter, simpleadapter

I am working on an Android application. In my app I have to use a adapter. So I used simple adapter.

```
int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.img1,
            R.drawable.img2,

};

List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
 for(int i=0;i<number.size();i++){
         HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
     hm.put("txt", number.get(i));
     hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
     aList.add(hm);
 }

String[] from = { "flag","txt"};

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] send = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.autocomplete_layout, from, send);
```

Now I want to use my own drawable arraylist instead of drawable from resourse.

```
Drawable d="some downloaded image from server"
```

Now I want to use the above d in hashmap.

```
hm.put("flag", d.toString() );
```

The above stamenet is not working.I know its beacause earlier i send image ids. Now I am converting image to string.

So I have to put my image  to hashmap hm. But how can I put if I use my downloaded drawable image?.

Comment: see this [example for How to show images from server](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html)

Comment: @gtumca-MAC.. I download all the images and stored in an arraylist<Drawable>..check my hashmap hm. there how can i use my arraylist?

Answer (score 2):

// this may helps you

[1] First of all You need

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm= new HashMap<String, Object>();
Bitmap bmImg;
```

[2] For Online Image need 1 Function to get it with Bitmap object

```
public void downloadFile(final String fileUrl) 
    {
        URL myFileUrl = null;
        try {
            myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            //int length = conn.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FAILED);
        }

    }
```

// for put online image in hasmap with thread and require data fill here

```
for(int i=0;i<number.size();i++){
     HashMap<String, Object> hm= new HashMap<String, Object>();
              new Thread() {
                            public void run() 
                            {    
                            downloadFile(smtLink[ii]);
                            hm.put("image", bmImg);
                        };
                }.start();              
              hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
              aList.add(hm);
```

}

// and need  viewbinder class

```
class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,String textRepresentation) 
        {
            if((view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap)) 
            {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;
                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

// now set this data with simple adapter like below, Here change as per your requirement with your adpter

```
adapater1 = new SimpleAdapter(News.this, list, R.layout.homrow, new String[] { "im", "Titel", "Sourcetag", "Date1","im1" }, 
                            new int[] { R.id.homerowmain,R.id.homerowtitle, R.id.homerowsourcetag,R.id.homerowdate, R.id.homerowimgaerrow });
                adapater1.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
                itemlist.setAdapter(adapater1);
```

Comment: Hi @ankitmakwana..Thanks for your reply..hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );..flags is an int array that contain drawable id. Our new images are downloaded one's so we cant use flags[i]. My questin is how can i add image in to alist..

Comment: just pass imgaeurl Array in forloop and give its postion and call function Download  function

Comment: downloadFile(smtLink[ii]); is your Array with contain allimagesurl

Comment: Oke..I have all image uris ..eg: int imageuri[];..Hashmap hm.add("flag",image[uri]);  list.add(hm).  simpleAdapter(News.this, list, R.layout.homrow, new String[] { "flag"}, 
                            new int[] { R.id.image });...Now also i wont get iamge

Comment: here bind your layout  SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.autocomplete_layout, from, send)

Comment: Bitmap bmImg; make sure its declare

Comment: [1] need populate item [2] then setadpter ok

Comment: temp.put("image", bmImg);..Where we are using temp.What is the relation with temp with list??..Sorry to disturb you but I am confused.

Comment: ita same as your hm list object you may change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16360/discussion-between-ankitmakwana-and-sarath)

Comment: pls check now i have change it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Integer[] flags = {
        R.drawable.Yourimg1, R.drawable.Yourimg2,
        R.drawable.Yourimg3, R.drawable.Yourimg4,          

};
```

Comment: My drawble images are not in resourse folder.I fetch that from server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your import you don't have android.R ...And add your own R file :)

Comment: @arnouf.. I think you did not get my question..In simple... hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
flags I contains the drawable id..Instead of this I want to use .Drawable d="some downloaded image"..So How can I pass my d to hm?